# Dwarves moving food, but not barrels or alcohol, to stockpile

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've placed a temporary stockpile to make sure my food doesn't spoil (I had a lot of *Fun* once before I learned that food can spoil if it isn't in a food stockpile). My dwarves happily moved all of my food stores to the temporary stockpile, but they left the barrels! I find this quite unsettling because they contain all of my precious booze.

I've made sure that the stockpile accepts ALL types of food, and there are at least 24 empty tiles in the stockpile, why won't they move my alcohol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check the number of [barrels and bins](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Stockpile#Max_bin.2Fbarrel) allowed in the stockpile? If you've created the stockpile using, for example, Animals and then changed it to include food, the stockpile will have both of those limits set to zero.